# assign list values to dictionary python

Tags: python, loops, replace

So I am working with a set of dictionarys consisting of

```
{'Summery':["00","01","02"],'Location':["03","04"],'Name':["05"]}
```

now each number correlates to the word count on each line

And in the text file I have, the lines that are formatted as so

```
Fun Reading Afterschool 50°N 50°E Library
Education Learning Study 51°N 51°E School
Exercise Play Social 52°N 52°E Playground
```

How Can I convert the input.txt to the desired output:

output.txt

```
{'Summery':["Fun","Reading","Aftershchool"],'Location':["50°N","50°E"],'Name':["Library"]}
{'Summery':["Education","Learning","Study"],'Location':["51°N","51°E"],'Name':["School"]}
{'Summery':["Exercise","Play","Social"],'Location':["52°N","52°E"],'Name':["Playground"]}
```

so far I have

```
file = open("input.txt", 'r')
lines = file.readlines()

list_word = []
for l in lines:
    list_word.append(l.split(" "))

my_list = [line.split(' , ')for line in open ("test")]

string1="".join(map(str,my_list))
print(string1)

new_main = open("output.txt", 'w')
new_main.write(string1)
new_main.close()
```

which prints and creates output.txt

```
['Fun Reading Afterschool 50°N 50°E Library\n']['Education Learning Study 51°N 51°E School\n']['Exercise Play Social 52°N 52°E Playground']
```

Comment: Do the keys *need* to use single quotes, or can you use double quotes, in which case you can just use `json.dumps` to produce valid JSON?

Comment: the quotes, don't matter. How would I add the json.dump to get it workiing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the summary is always 3 words, the location 2 and the name 1 word (each seperated by one whitespace), you can take the wanted words based on their indices.

```
for string in string1:
    splits = string.split(" ")
    
    summary = splits[0:3]
    location = splits[3:5]
    name = splits[5:6]
    
    print(f"Summary: {summary}, location: {location}, name: {name}")
```

Comment: I havent managed to get this to print out the desired output. (sorry new to python)

Comment: The error I am getting is as follows     splits = string.split(" ")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: This is because your strings are stored as lists in your "string1" array. Try doing string = string[0]. The best solution would be not to keep them as lists but let's stick to this since you're new :)

Comment: now its just broken up the lists into individual characters and fed them into the summery. Summary: ['['], location: [], name: []
Summary: ["'"], location: [], name: []
Summary: ['F'], location: [], name: []
Summary: ['u'], location: [], name: []
Summary: ['n'], location: [], name: []

Comment: Got it - for string in string1::
    string = string[0]
    splits = string.split(" ") Thanks